# Active_shipping Gem Load Error when running rails s after updating to Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just updated to Rails 5.2 (from 4.2) and am getting this error whenever I try to run `rails s`:

```
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:84:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'active_shipping'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: undefined method `superclass_delegating_accessor' for ActiveMerchant::Shipping::Carrier:Class
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/active_utils-2.2.3/lib/active_utils/common/posts_data.rb:5:in `included'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/active_shipping-0.12.6/lib/active_shipping/shipping/carrier.rb:5:in `include'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/active_shipping-0.12.6/lib/active_shipping/shipping/carrier.rb:5:in `<class:Carrier>'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/active_shipping-0.12.6/lib/active_shipping/shipping/carrier.rb:3:in `<module:Shipping>'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/active_shipping-0.12.6/lib/active_shipping/shipping/carrier.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveMerchant>'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/active_shipping-0.12.6/lib/active_shipping/shipping/carrier.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/active_shipping-0.12.6/lib/active_shipping.rb:51:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
/Users/lizbayardelle/Dropbox/Code/MAB/config/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `require'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:9:in `require'
bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
    from /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
    from /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
    from /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
    from /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
    from /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    from /Users/lizbayardelle/Dropbox/Code/MAB/config/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `require'
    from /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
    from /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    from /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    from /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    from /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    from /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

I have tried `bundle update active_shipping` and `gem install active_shipping`, but it looks like I have the most updated version of the gem.

Can anyone help me parse this error?  Similar bundler errors seem to be part and parcel of updating a Rails version, but I can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: Try updating your version of Active Merchant, see https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/pull/1418/files

Comment: @DamianSimonPeter I didn't previously need Active Merchant to make Active Shipping run, but I installed it anyway and it worked!  Thank you!

Comment: @DamianSimonPeter If you want to write this up as an answer I'll happily select it!

Comment: Thanks @Liz I will do that right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your version of `active_merchant`. The `superclass_delegating_accessor` was removed from [this PR](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/pull/1418/files).